# Forcing an ember app to use https

Tags: ember.js

I've got an ember app running on Heroku and want to force the all users to use https. I haven't been able to work out how to redirect to an https url. I was hoping I could either redirect on a specific route, like login, or have all routes use https but haven't been able to find any info on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should control the redirection of HTTP to HTTPS in the application layer. You can do that in any language.

- Ruby: http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-ssl
- Go: https://github.com/kr/secureheader

If you have to do it in client-side JavaScript look at the `window.location.protocol`. Something like:

```
if(window.location.protocol == "http:") {
  window.location.protocol = "https:"
}
```

Comment: The client-side approach works a treat, thanks Dane!

Comment: Just as a followup, the above approach doesn't work for Firefox and an error is thrown.

`if window.location.href.match('http:') window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('http', 'https')` works on latest FF and Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

Ember is for one-page-app. If you app is under https, all the routes will be under https.

```
https://www.securedomain.io/my-awesome-app/index.html
```

The posts route will be

```
https://www.securedomain.io/my-awesome-app/index.html#posts
```

etc...

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. What I want to do is redirect if a user hits one of my routes using a non-https route:

http://myapp.com/#/login

to

https://myapp.com/#/login